# Load WordPress 5.2 jQuery Script From CDN

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Until WP 5.0 the below code worked. After WP 5.2 it doesn't work anymore. I receive an error that suggest to use `wp_enqueue_scripts` and to not use `wp_deregister_script anymore`.

```
add_action('init', function() 
{
  if (is_admin()) 
  {
    return;
  }

  global $wp_scripts;
  if (isset($wp_scripts->registered['jquery']->ver)) 
  {
    $ver = $wp_scripts->registered['jquery']->ver;
  } 
  else 
  {
    $ver = '1.12.4';
  }

  wp_deregister_script('jquery');
  wp_register_script('jquery', "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/$ver/jquery.min.js", false, $ver);
});
```

Comment: Why are you trying to register the same version of jQuery as WP does. If you just want to be able to use it, @johannes' reply is on point. You simply need to enqueue the script.

Comment: I want to load jQuery from CDN instead locally - it has an impact on Google Pagespeed Insights. And also to remove the jquery-migrate.min.js - because it's not used in most of the cases.

Comment: If that is the case try using `'wp_enqueue_scripts'` hook instead of `'init'`

Comment: Also take a look at this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/262301/cannot-deregister-a-script-using-wp-deregister-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to load jQuery from Google CDN - however WordPress adds -wp to the output script version: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4-wp/jquery.min.js - instead of https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js. This is the function I used that works:

```
// Load jQuery from Google CDN
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    if (is_admin()) {
        return;
    }

    global $wp_scripts;
    if (isset($wp_scripts->registered['jquery']->ver)) {
        $ver = str_replace('-wp', '', $wp_scripts->registered['jquery']->ver);

    } else {
        $ver = '1.12.4';
    }

    wp_dequeue_script('jquery');
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/$ver/jquery.min.js", false, $ver);
});
```

and to load a specific version of jQuery from CDN I used this code that works

```
// Load jQuery from Google CDN
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    if (is_admin()) {
        return;
    } else {
        $ver = '1.12.4';
    }

    wp_dequeue_script('jquery');
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/$ver/jquery.min.js", false, $ver);
});
```

These functions also remove the jquery-migrate.min.js from loading.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually sufficient to insert this into the `head` tag in the `header.php` file:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?>
```

And Wordpress does the rest...